# html5 cache -> "network: *" doesn't work

Tags: caching, html, manifest, whitelist

I am trying a simple test with the html 5 cache.

Here is a simple web page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="test.manifest">
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <img src="http://www.somewebsite.com/picture.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v0.1

NETWORK:
http://www.somewebsite.com/
```

This work fine, the picture is displayed.

My problem is that I won't be able to know from where the picture will come. Here comes the online whitelist wildcard flag, that is supposed to solve my problem.

But with the manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v0.1

NETWORK:
*
```

The image is not displayed (tested on safari / safari mobile / firefox).

What is not working ?

Is there another way to turn the online whitelist wildcard flag on ?

Answer (score 4):

Tested in Firefox 3.6.4:

```
NETWORK:
http://*
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html), when "the online whitelist wildcard flag is open" (i.e., the `NETWORK:` `*` format),

> Subresources, such as style sheets,
>   images, etc, would only be cached
>   using the regular HTTP caching
>   semantics, however.

which seems to be the "what is not working".  To cache subresources in the HTML5 way, the manifest must either list them in a `CACHE:` section, or use specific "online whitelist namespaces" as you did in your first version.

Answer (score -1):

I wish to use an svg font in a webapp aimed for mobile safari (mobile safari only reads the svg font format for @font-face) Mobile safari also requires the font-ID, which is included at the end of the file name, but included after number sign (#):

font-name.svg#123456789

This is not working in the cache-manifest for the site and, with the limited feedback one gets from mobile safari, I am only guessing that the # is causing the font-id to be read as a comment, and not part of the actual file name.

Is there a way to 'trick' the cache manifest into reading this differently? Perhaps with a wildcard after the SVG? Or an ascii-only trick?